Build AUFS/UnionFS driver for Linux 6.6.31
I want to build the AUFS Linux filesystem for Linux kernel 6.6.31.
Where can I get the source code and how to build it and lastly, how do I get the .ko file?

As far as I know, AUFS is a bit of ancient history and use of OverlayFS is encouraged instead. Is there any specific reason why you want AUFS?

@schaiba I need AUFS for a compatibility of an old linux distro im hacking.
If u prefer overlayfs then answer about it but i dont know how to use it

Just asking how to use it is kind of broad. Instead, explain what you'd do (preferably with exact commands) if you had AUFS, and we can tell you how to do the equivalent with overlayfs.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica mount /rw and /ro together and form /new

Like this: mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/ro,upperdir=/rw/upper,workdir=/rw/work  /new

Why are u giving the answer in the comments

I follow this guy (Junjiro R. Okajima) on Github.
They seem to have been maintaining this driver for some years. I just follow the instructions and patch the kernel. When I compile my own kernel, I am able to take advantage of the drivers.
Here's my patch script I use after cloning the repository. Hope this helps!
